# Differentiate between Click or Drag on ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, dragula, ng2-dragula

On the [demo page](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/) it is shown, that you can differentiate between a normal left click and the start of a drag.

> Click or Drag! Fires a click when the mouse button is released before a `mousemove` event, otherwise a drag event is fired. No extra configuration is necessary.

I'm now using a `isInDragMode` variable, which is set on the `drag` event and unset in `onSelect`, but here it is stated that *No extra configuration is necessary*.

So is there a solution out of the box? How does it look like with `ng2-dragula`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below way

```
var flag = 0;
var element = xxxx;
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    flag = 0;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    flag = 1;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if(flag === 0){
        console.log("click");
    }
    else if(flag === 1){
        console.log("drag");
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I think that his solutions is better than your. In this concept you don't control mousedown action at all if you forget about flag in your implementation. It's really unclear.

Comment: This is what I felt easy, if you have any other implementation, let him know.

Comment: He have a solution: "I'm now using a isInDragMode variable, which is set on the drag event and unset in onSelect, but here it is stated that No extra configuration is necessary.", and this is better IMO.